# How to use expect script in ruby on rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, expect

Can you please help me?. How can i use the expect script in ruby.

```
spawn scp /tmp/*.txt remoteserver:/vg/
expect "password"
send "MY PASSWORD"
interact
```

Because, i need to transfer the bulk files from one server to another server through scp command. But, when i use the wildcard file transfer (/tmp/*.txt) it shows the following error

**No such file or directory
Killed by signal 1.**

Then, i had changed my code like as follows. (Note: i have used the file name directly).

```
spawn scp /tmp/first.txt remoteserver:/vg/
expect "password"
send "MY PASSWORD"
interact
```

So , I have just jump into rails.

```
$files = Dir.glob("/tmp/*.txt")
for f in @files
[I need to use the expect script here]
expect {....#{f}...}
end
```

Thanks

Comment: Just curious why you are not using key exchanges?  Then you wouldn't need an expect script.  (I know scp has some issues when being called from the command line, so you could try using rsync)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You do want to use ssh keys for this. It's not hard to set up, then you don't have to worry about it.

You probably want your expect script to look like this:

```
set scp_command [linsert $argv0 scp]
lappend scp_command remote_server:/vg/
eval spawn $scp_command

expect password
send "MYPASSWORD\r"
expect eof
```

and the Ruby part would be something like

```
system "expect", "expect_script.exp", Dir.glob("/tmp/*.txt")
```

Answer (score 0):

Glenn mentioned using ssh keys - they certainly make your life easier when you're working with Expect scripts.

A few year ago I wrote a blog post on how to use generate and use ssh keys with putty on Windows.

http://soniahamilton.wordpress.com/2008/09/05/how-to-use-putty-with-ssh-keys-on-windows/